# JList with 3 JLabel inside

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I'm looking for a possibility to show a `List` with comments in `Java`. 
So I thought I could use the `JList` and make an own `CellRenderer`. 
The problem is that I want to show the name, the date and the comment in one Item of the list.

How could this be realized with a `JList` and a `CellRenderer`? Or do I have to use something else instead of the `JList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you want a `JTable` rather than a `JList`. That will give you different columns where you can put your name, date and comment.

I'm sure you could also solve this using a `CellRenderer` that is a `JPanel` on which you put whatever you want, but I'd advise you to try out `JTable` first.

Comment: Thanks I took a JList with an own `CellRenderer`. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `JLabel` as the `ListCellRenderer` component (like `DefaultListCellRenderer`) you could prefix the text with `"<html>"` and format the "layout" of the list cells with HTML.

Comment: this sounds great.. I'll test this.